# How can I get image from this python code?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image
new_im = Image.new('RGB', (100,200), (255,255,255))
new_im.save("MonImage.png", "PNG")
```

i use this code in visual studio to create an image but i cant show it

Comment: What do you mean "cant show it". Did you want the image to open in a separate window? Does the image file not get created in the directory you expect it to write to?

Comment: Have you tried viewing it within the file?

Comment: If you do `new_im.show()` instead of `save`, you can certainly see it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to saving the file to disk (via `new_im.save`) you can also display the image with

```
new_im.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you (your picture will be opened in a new window)

`new_im.show()`